# How do I use copy mode when checking out multiple git repositories in buildbot

Tags: git, buildbot

I have multiple git repositories to have some interdependencies between them.  I need to check all of them out when doing a full system build.
With buildbot, I can use the `mode='clobber'` parameter to the Git source class constructor, but this causes all of the repositories to be checked out each time:

```
factory.addStep(Git(repourl='ssh://build@build/repo1', mode='clobber', workdir='build/repo1'))
factory.addStep(Git(repourl='ssh://build@build/repo2', mode='clobber', workdir='build/repo2'))
factory.addStep(Git(repourl='ssh://build@build/repo3', mode='clobber', workdir='build/repo3'))
```

I would like to use `mode='copy'`, but when I do that, the source for all three repositories gets checked out in the same location, eg. `.../source/` rather than `.../source/repo1` `.../source/repo2` `.../source/repo3`

Is there a way to indicate to buildbot to keep clean copies of each repository separately?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use subrepos to bundle the different repos?

Comment: THat might be my only option... I was trying to avoid that, because of bureaucratic issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With buildbot 0.8.5 and above, you can use the new master-side source steps (which live at `buildbot.steps.source.git.Git` instead of `builbot.steps.source.Git`) and then `Git(..., mode='full', ...)` will do a checkout plus `git clean -xfd`.

Also, there is work under way to properly support for using code for multiple sources, that will be included in buildbot 0.8.7, when it is released.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a parent repo which would be checked out in `source/` by buildbot.
Except that parent repo would reference all your other repos as **[submodules](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html)**.
And when a submodule is checked out within a parent repo, it will be checked out in its own (repo1, repo2, ...) directory.

You just need to adjust **[buildbot Git parameters](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/0.8.1/Git.html)** in order to take into accounts submodules.

```
submodules
```

> (optional): when initializing/updating a Git repository, this decides whether or not buildbot should consider git submodules.
>   Default: False.

Comment: Sounds like that might be my only option, short of changing buildbot to take an additional parameter...